# About a loop that creates dynamic buttons, but cannot give proper values

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

I am having a small issue, and it would be very nice if some of you could realize about what kind of logic is missing here, since I cannot seem to find it:

I have an array with the results of some previous operation. Let's say that the array is:

```
var results = [0, 1];
```

And then I have a bunch of code where I create some buttons, and inside a `for` loop I assign a different function to those buttons, depending on the position of the array. The problem is that for some reason, all the buttons created (two in this case) come out with the function assigned to the last value of the array (in this case, both would come out as one, instead of the first with 0 and the second with 1)

This is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var br2 = b.document.createElement("br");
    var reslabel = b.document.createTextNode(Nom[results[i]].toString());
    var card = document.createElement("input");
    card.type = "button";
    id = results[i]; // this is the problematic value. 
    card.onclick = newcard; // this function will use the above value.
    card.value = "Show card";
    divcontainer.appendChild(br2);
    divcontainer.appendChild(reslabel);
    divcontainer.appendChild(card);
}
```

As it is, this code produces as many buttons as elements in the array, each with its proper label (it retrieves labels from another array). Everything is totally fine. Then, I click the button. All the buttons should run the `newcard` function. That function needs the `id` variable, so in this case it should be:

- First button: runs `newcard` using variable `id` with value 0
- Second button: runs `newcard` using variable `id` with value 1

But both buttons run using `id` as 1... why is that?

It might be very simple, or maybe is just that in my timezone is pretty late already :-) Anyways, I would appreciate any comment. I am learning a lot around here...

Thanks!

Edit to add the definition of newcard:

```
function newcard() {
    id = id;
    var toerase = window.document.getElementById("oldcard");
    toerase.innerHTML = "";
    generate();
}
```

the function `generate` will generate some content using `id`. Nothing wrong with it, it generates the content fine, is just that `id` is always set to the last item in the array.

Comment: What's the definition of newcard?

Comment: added definition of newcard

Comment: You don't actually use `id` inside of `newcard` (`id = id` does nothing). Do you use it in `generate`?

Comment: yes, I need the `id` value to be defined, because `generate` will ask for it.

Comment: This is not an *exact* duplicate of the linked question, despite the fact that I initially thought it was, and voted to close. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` is a global variable, and when the loop ends it is set to the last value on the array. When the event handler code runs and asks for the value of `id`, it will get that last value.

You need to create a closure to capture the current `results[i]` and pass it along (this is a very common pitfal, see [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)). Since `newcard` is very simple, and `id` is actually used in `generate`, you could modify `generate` to take the id as a parameter. Then you won't need `newcard` anymore, you can do this instead:

```
card.onclick = (function(id) { 
    return function() { 
        window.document.getElementById("oldcard").innerHTML = "";
        generate(id);
    }; 
}(results[i]));
```

What this does is define and immediately invoke a function that is passed the current `results[i]`. It returns another function, which will be your actual `onclick` handler. That function has access to the `id` parameter of the outer function (that's called a *closure*). On each iteration of the loop, a new closure will be created, trapping each separate `id` for its own use.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem and your solution, although I cannot really use it 100% because I cannot set `generate` to take a parameter (due to other parts of the program needing it like this), but with your explanation as starting point, I will see what can I do.

Comment: Well, I got it to work with minimal changes to your example. Excellent! This was really something... I will bookmark this answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Before going on, a **HUGE** thank you to *bfavaretto* for explaining some scoping subtelties that totally escaped me.  It seems that in addition to the problems you had, you were also suffering from scoping, which bit me while I was trying to craft an answer.

Anyway, here's an example that works.  I'm using forEach, which may not be supported on some browsers.  However it does get around some of the scoping nastiness that was giving you grief:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var results = [0,1];
results.forEach( function(result) {
    var card = document.createElement("input");
    card.type = "button";
    card.onclick = function() {
        newcard( result );
    } 
    card.value = "Show card";
    document.body.appendChild(card);
}); 

function newcard(x) {
   alert(x);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you decide to stick with a traditional loop, please see bfavaretto's answer.

Comment: very well explained, and I saw some things I was doing wrong thanks to your explanation. Still, the problem remains. I have done exactly like that: changing the onclick assignment and changing the definition of newcard. But I put a `console.log(id)` inside the function of the onclick, and it's always the last value... I will stop now, and tomorrow I will re-read your answer and keep working on it.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell That won't work, because (1) `id` is global, and (2) it is being used in `generate`. The latter would have to be passed an id too. And (3) looks like you forgot to create the actual closure, you'd need something like `card.onclick = (function(id) { return function() { newcard(id); }; }(results[i]))`.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Actually, the code you showed won't work as you're assigning a function of one parameter to onclick, which expects a function of no parameters.  However, the code I displayed is broken, which is odd, as I've written code like that dozens of times with no problem.  Looking at it further to see what I missed...

Comment: See my answer (formatting is better there). I'm actually assigning a function with no parameters as the event handler (which is actually passed one parameter, the event object, which I left out).

Comment: @bfavaretto Actually, I modified my answer with full code that does work.  It's a loop oddity...

Comment: It works now because with `forEach` you're actually creating a closure - plus you got rid of the global `id` variable.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok, I'm completely lost. Why was I creating a closure with forEach but not with for, and why did id being global have anything to do with it?  I thought closures captured free variables and that was that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21549/discussion-between-bfavaretto-and-ronaldbarzell)